# enter String inside a another string quotes

Tags: java

I need to use a string something like this

```
String x = "return "My name is X" ";
```

We can see the issue is first and second quotes wll be treated as a String in itself , but actually first and last quote should form 1 string , while 2nd and 3rd quotes should form another string inside that.

Any solution for this?

Comment: String x = "return \"My name is X\" ";

Comment: Yes: escape the quotes...

Comment: What you need is escape chars

Answer (score 3):

Escape the quotes or use String concatenation like

```
String x = "return \"My name is X\" ";
```

or

```
String x = "return " + '"' + "My name is X" + '"' + " ";
```

Comment: This doesnt work String x = "return &quot;My name is X &quot; ";
Any idea why this doesnt work?

Comment: @user3417179 Java is not a web-browser, and will not read HTML entity values as characters

Answer (score 2):

You just need to escape the double-quote within the string literal:

```
String x = "return \"My name is X\" ";
```

There are other characters which can be escaped like this too - for example:

```
String tab = "before\tafter";
```

(That's "before", then a tab, then "after".)

See the [JLS section 3.10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-EscapeSequence) for all escape sequences.